# How do I set persistent environment variables for root?

Tags: root, environment-variables

To create persistent environment variables, I add the script file to /etc/profile.d directory, for example:

```
# my script
export MY_VAR=var_value
```

This works properly for current user:

```
alex@alex-64:~$ echo $MY_VAR
var_value
```

Now I need the same environment variables for the root user, but /etc/profile.d script doesn't work for root:

```
alex@alex-64:~$ echo $MY_VAR
var_value
alex@alex-64:~$ sudo su
root@alex-64:/home/alex# echo $MY_VAR

root@alex-64:/home/alex#
```

How can I set the same variables for the root?

Comment: [This question about how to preserve a particular variable from the *caller's* environment when running `sudo` is very related.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607545/maven-java-home-is-not-defined-correctly/607710#607710) (But it is not a duplicate because this question is about how to customize root's *own* environment.)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

*sudo* does not normally preserve local environment variables. You should use it with the `-E` switch to do so, i.e. `sudo -E su` will preserve *$MYVAR* for root.

Alternatively, to create persistent variables that are truly system-wide, you should set them in `/etc/environment`.

Comment: Does not work, /etc/environemnt variables are not set for sudo

Comment: @FredericYesidPeñaSánchez it did for me on CentOS. You don't script in there, you just do simple assignments on each line, i.e. `FOO=bar`

Comment: Thanks, worked.  `/etc/environment` values were available as root after restarting my terminal (not before)

Comment: Worked for me right away on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 10):

`Defaults env_reset` in `/etc/sudoers` will reset root's `PATH` defined by `/etc/environment`.

You could modify it to `Defaults !env_reset` to disable resetting or add:

```
Defaults secure_path="my/custom/path:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

Comment: If I want to use the second solution(means add path to secure_path), what is key?! path is just value. I want to add ANDROID_NDK to environment variables for root. So for now, I just using the first one(!env_reset).Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Like the process you define your own environment variable, for example by editing '~/.bashrc', you can define root's environment variable by editing '/root/.bashrc'.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass environment variables using `env` flag. I always need to get around proxies and this is a constant issue for me. Especially when you need to pass `PATH` and proxy environment variables.

Command:

```bsh
sudo env "ENV=$ENV1" "ENV2=$ENV2" [command]
```

And you can add it as an alias (add this `.bashrc`, `.bash_aliases` or `.zshrc` etc).

Example of my alias:

```bsh
alias psudo='sudo env "PATH=$PATH" "HTTP_PROXY=$HTTP_PROXY" "HTTPS_PROXY=$HTTPS_PROXY" "http_proxy=$http_proxy" "https_proxy=$http_proxy"'
```

Be mindful that this obviously reduces the security of sudo.