# How to get the long 'less' prompt with sudo?

Tags: sudo, less

I have added the following to my user's `.bashrc` file to get a longer prompt in `less`:

```
export LESS="-M"
```

This is added to the root user's `.bashrc` file as well, so when I `sudo bash` to get a root shell, it works just as well.

But when using `sudo less …`, it doesn't apply. There's only the simple colon prompt giving me no information at all where I am in the file. How can I change that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should keep this environmental variable when running sudo. Edit the file `/etc/sudoers` and add

```
Defaults        env_keep += "LESS"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using aliases in your .bashrc file not export. You need to be editing your /etc/bash.bashrc file to inclide,

```
 alias less="sudo less -m"
```

more info from this [POST](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22037/aliases-not-available-when-using-sudo)

Comment: The following question has answers that explain why exporting the variables do not work: http://askubuntu.com/questions/161924/how-do-i-set-persistent-environment-variables-for-root

If you want to use your current method, you can use 'sudo -E', but setting up an alias as Mike suggests, is probably a better way to do it.

Comment: Not all `less` should do `sudo`...