# Maven: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly

Tags: software-installation, java, maven-3

I've installed and configured Maven and Java. I can **successfully** run

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

But when I run

```
sudo mvn spring-boot:run
```

I am getting `Maven: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly`

When I do

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/home/ubuntu/jdk1.8.0_26
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*You will probably want to edit your `sudoers` file with `sudo visudo`, find the line `Defaults        env_reset` and add a line `Defaults        env_keep = "JAVA_HOME"` below it. See below for explanation, details, and alternatives.*

### Why `sudo` Is Clearing `JAVA_HOME`

When you run a command with `sudo`, by default your environment is *not* passed intact. Most environment variables are removed, for security, and this is usually desirable. As [`man sudoers`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man5/sudoers.5.html) says, in the section on "Command environment":

> Since environment variables can influence program behavior, `sudoers`
>   provides a means to restrict which variables from the user's
>   environment are inherited by the command to be run. There are two
>   distinct ways `sudoers` can deal with environment variables.
>
> By default, the `env_reset` option is enabled. This causes commands to
>   be executed with a new, minimal environment. On AIX (and Linux systems
>   without PAM), the environment is initialized with the contents of the
>   `/etc/environment` file. The new environment contains the TERM, PATH,
>   HOME, MAIL, SHELL, LOGNAME, USER, USERNAME and SUDO_* variables in
>   addition to variables from the invoking process permitted by the
>   `env_check` and `env_keep` options. This is effectively a whitelist
>   for environment variables.
>
> If, however, the env_reset option is disabled, any variables not
>   explicitly denied ***....***

### Letting `JAVA_HOME` Through One Time

One option, if you rarely run `mvn spring-boot:run` as root and prefer not to change your configuration at all, is simply to pass on the value of `JAVA_HOME` manually:

```
sudo JAVA_HOME="$JAVA_HOME" mvn spring-boot:run
```

When you run that:

1. The shell performs [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and [quote removal](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quote-Removal), replacing `"$JAVA_HOME"` with the value (i.e., contents) of `JAVA_HOME`. If that contains no blank spaces, the quotes are not necessary (their purpose here is to prevent [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting)).
2. `sudo` is called with three arguments: `JAVA_HOME=...`, where `...` is the value of `JAVA_HOME` when you ran the command; `mvn`, and `spring-boot:run`.
3. `sudo` recognizes `variable=value` syntax, and knows to run `mvn` with `JAVA_HOME` set to the specified value. (`spring-boot:run` is passed as the first command-line argument to `mvn`).

To pass *all* your environment variables through, you can run `sudo -E mvn spring-boot:run`, but this is potentially less secure and not ideal because `JAVA_HOME` is the only variable whose value you need preserved (besides the handful of variables whose values are automatically preserved even with `env_reset`).

### Letting `JAVA_HOME` Through Every Time

Although you could disable `env_reset` in your `sudoers` file, this would pass almost all a user's environment variables through every time `sudo` is run, and for this reason is not recommended.

Instead, I recommend you edit your `sudoers` file and **add an appropriate `env_keep` line** after the `env_reset` line.

- Please do not edit `/etc/sudoers` directly. Instead, you should always use the [`visudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man8/visudo.8.html) command for this, which checks to ensure your syntax is correct (preventing the creation of an invalid `sudoers` file which [locks down `sudo` until fixed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-a-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-out-an-error-and-not-allowi)).

Run:

```
sudo visudo
```

This will use your default command-line text editor. If you want to use a different editor, you can run `visudo` with it assigned to the `VISUAL` environment variable. For example:

- `sudo VISUAL=nano visudo`
- `sudo VISUAL=gedit visudo`

<sup>(`VISUAL` isn't so named after the "vis" in `visudo`; instead, it's the environment variable for specifying default text editors. You can also use the `EDITOR` variable, but `VISUAL` takes priority if set.)</sup>

Running `visudo` opens up a temporary copy of your `sudoers` file in a text editor; on exit, changes made to this copy are written to `/etc/sudoers`.

Find the line that says:

```
Defaults        env_reset
```

Add a line just under it, saying:

```
Defaults        env_keep = "JAVA_HOME"
```

(*If* you already have an `env_keep` line, add `JAVA_HOME` to the quoted list of allowed variables. The variable names are separated from one another with spaces.)

Save the file and quit the text editor. Now, when users run commands with `sudo`, the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable will be preserved.

Comment: Thanks that worked. One question though, I am able to run `sudo echo $JAVA_HOME` without any problems. Why is that ? I did not modify the sudoers file btw

Comment: @kranthi117 Because even when you run `sudo echo $JAVA_HOME`, the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is evaluated as your user, *not* as root. Specifically, first the shell expands `$JAVA_HOME`, before invoking the `sudo` command. `sudo` then receives `echo` as its first argument and the *value* (i.e., contents) `JAVA_HOME` had *in the calling shell's own environment* as its second argument. One way to see the value of an environment variable when sudo'd to root is to run a root shell with sudo and make that shell evaluate it instead of the non-root calling shell: `sudo sh -c 'echo $JAVA_HOME'`