# Maven environment variable not working on other terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, java, environment-variables, maven-3

When I run `echo $PATH` and `echo $JAVA_HOME` command as a normal user, I get `jdk` path variables set. But when I run as a root user, the variables are not set there.

I copied maven binary folder to `/opt` then tried to install maven environment variable using command:

```
export PATH=/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:$PATH
```

When I run `mvn -version` in the current terminal I see maven variables set but when I run the command from a new terminal, it says maven is not installed.

And when I run `mvn -version` as a root user, from the current ternimal, it also gives shows maven not being installed.

Please help me to configure maven.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set persistent environment variables for root?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/161924/how-do-i-set-persistent-environment-variables-for-root)

Comment: The link which is provided as a duplicate post of is not what I am asking for. I want to set environment variables permanently not just in a terminal

Comment: If you set them in `/etc/environment` they'll be visible by all processes run after login (unless the process itself or one of its ancestors explicitly unsets them).

Comment: @pranishres: Then the keyword is "permanently". Take a look at [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay finally what I did was the same I did for installing java jdk environment i.e adding maven variables in `/etc/profile`. The steps are described below:-

1. sudo pluma /etc/profile
2. Add these commands at the end of the text file

   `export M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9`

   `export M2=$M2_HOME/bin`

   `export PATH=$M2:$PATH`
3. Reload `profile` by typing `source /etc/profile` in command line
4. Restart the system
5. Verify `M2` by typing `echo $M2` in command line
6. Verify `PATH` by typing `echo $PATH` in command line. Check if there is maven directory in the `PATH` variable or not.
7. Check `maven version` by typing `mvn -version` in command line