# "/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory" even though it is in PATH

Tags: 16.04, nodejs, npm

I'm trying to get nodejs working. However, it tells me that node is not in my bin even though I downloaded the binary and added the location to my path.

`> echo $PATH
...:/home/jvdh/node-v8.11.2-linux-x64/bin`

`>sudo npm install -g bitcore`
`/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory`

Comment: did you try without sudo?

Comment: that works better but then I get this: `npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.`

Comment: ok.. One question. where (which file) did you set this in path variable?

Comment: $HOME/node-v8.11.2-linux-x64/bin

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/161930/401032

Comment: Also . https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install nodejs8

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Install nodejs10

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Then try again with node

Comment: taken from here

https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Comment: Here are the [installation instructions for **newer versions**](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall) of `nodejs`.

Comment: For me the problem was also that npm wasnt installed

Answer (score 8):

Usually this is a simple naming problem, when you install from a package manager your bin file may be called nodejs so you just need to symlink it using the command:

`ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26320915/470749

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 20.04, you can install node.js and npm:

```
sudo apt install nodejs npm
```